# Casting to int in awk

Tags: awk, casting

I'm looking for a method to cast a string to an int in awk. I have the following which appears to be doing a string comparison

(***note***: field `$5` is a percentage in one of two formats: `80%` or `9.0%`)

```
awk '{if (substr($5,1,(length($5)-1)) >= 90) ...
```

So, when I change it to:

```
awk '{if (substr($5,1,(length($5)-1))+0 >= 90+0 ) ...
```

It compares as I intended.  Is this an appropriate cast?  Is there a 'better' way to perform the cast?

Comment: why the +0, why not $5+0 or does that not work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just use +0. say variable `v` is your percentage value.

```
$ awk -v v="80.1%" 'BEGIN{print v+0.1}'
80.2
```

You do not have to get rid of the `%` sign.

Answer (score 28):

Most new awks have an int() function.

But the method for casting documented in 'The Awk Programming Language' is shown as you do it, by using numericValue and `+0`. I don't have the book handy, but I think you can also cast for float value by using `+0.0`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_12), `int(x)` is POSIX compliant. The number will still be a float (since all numbers in awk are floating-point) but it will be truncated to an int.

---

Adding 0 won't convert a string into an int. It will convert it to a float.

If you have an old `awk` based on [The One True AWK](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) by Brian Kernighan, such as [macOS `awk`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html) or [FreeBSD `awk`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&sektion=1), you will see [this](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&sektion=1#end) at the bottom of the manpage:

```
BUGS
     There are no explicit conversions between numbers and strings.  To force
     an expression to be treated as a number add 0 to it; to force it to be
     treated as a string concatenate "" to it.

     The scope rules for variables in functions are a botch; the syntax is
     worse.
```

**To force an expression to be treated as a number add 0 to it**

---

If you don't care about floats and you have `gawk` you can also use [`strtonum`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strtonum-Function.html)

---

Other sources:

[OS X version of AWK, which is derived from "The One True AWK” by Brian Kernighan](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html)

All numbers in `awk` are floating-point:

[Search "All arithmetic shall follow the semantics of floating-point arithmetic as specified by the ISO C standard"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tab41)

[Search "all numbers in awk are floating"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)