# Multiply two value integer and float and get output in integer format means after decimal value it should not give 0

Tags: unix, awk

I am getting '$2*$1 = 1.5450` can it become a integer value like 1.545

file1

1 1.545 1.5450

Command used

awk -F" " '{ if('$2*$1==$3) {print $1,$2,$3,"True"}  else {print $1,$2,$3,"False"}}'

Output is

1 1.545 1.5450 False

Comment: looks lie a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808971/casting-to-int-in-awk

Comment: The question is totally unclear. If you care about columns 13 and 15, why are you multiplying columns 1 and 12? And why are you checking whether column 6 is 1 in your sample script?

Comment: I actually get `True` with both native OS X awk and gawk. What version of awk are you using?

Comment: This is my awk version GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Comment: It's curious. I have the same version and get `True`. (I assume you don't really have that extra single quote in front of the `$2` of your if condition.) Is this really the command you are running or have you simplified it in some way?